# recursion tree and binary tree cost calculation

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I've got the following recursion:

```
T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + O(n)
```

The height of the tree would be log3/2 of 2.  Now the recursion tree for this recurrence is not a complete binary tree.  It has missing nodes lower down.  This makes sense to me, however I don't understand how the following small omega notation relates to the cost of all leaves in the tree.

> *"... the total cost of all leaves would then be Theta (n^log3/2 of 2) which, since log3/2 of 2 is a constant strictly greater then 1, is small omega(n lg n)."*

Can someone please help me understand how the `Theta(n^log3/2 of 2)` becomes `small omega(n lg n)`?

Comment: This can't make sense to anyone unless you can show us the Theta and small omega functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, to answer your explicit question about why `n^(log_1.5(2))` is `omega(n lg n)`:
For all k > 1, n^k grows faster than `n lg n`. (Powers grow faster than logs eventually). Therefore since `2 > 1.5`, `log_1.5(2) > 1`, and thus `n^(log_1.5(2))` grows faster than `n lg n`. And since our function is in `Theta(n^(log_1.5(2)))`, it must also be in `omega(n lg n)`